# change multiple files commandline

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have separated some tracks from mp3 mixes using mp3splt.

BASH:   `(mp3splt -c('**!!***use .cue file***!!**') [cuefile.cue] [nonstopmix.mp3] ~for anyone interested, is in the Ubu repos~)`

And I ended up with these filenames: "Antares" - 01 - "Xibalba".mp3 which is not a format I prefer, now I've made it a little project to change them with a shell script but its more difficult than I anticipated.

I want to change the filename from:

```
"Antares" - 01 - "Xibalba".mp
```

to:

```
01-Antares_-_Xibalba.mp3
```

so far I've used :

```
for var in *.mp3; do mv $var {var/"/}; done
```

and I could repeat that until I'm through, delete the 0x number and add one but I'd like to do it more efficient.

Could anyone give me a pointer (*!not a script!*) ?
I'd still like to write it myself but there's so much options that I'm a bit lost.

so far I thought to use this program flow:

1. read all the filenames containing .mp3 and declare as variable $var
2. strip $var from quotes
3. select 0x number, append delimiter _ (0x_)
4. move 0x_ to the beginning of the string
5. select remaining ' -  - ' and change to '*-*'

done

which bash programs to use? especially changing the 0x puzzles me cuz I need a loop which increments this number and test if it is present in the filename variable and then it has to be changed.

Comment: PHP or perl be easier

Comment: yes perl is a good option, looking into it too

Comment: If you don't want to read my too fully answered response (with code), just take a look @the `rename` Perl's command. =)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
rename -n 's/"(\w+)"\s+-\s*(\d+)\s*-\s*"(\w+)"\.mp/$2-$1_-_$3.mp3/' *mp
```

from the `shell` prompt. It's very useful, you can put some [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) tricks like I does in a substitution.
You can remove the `-n` (dry-run mode switch) when your tests become valids.

[image: warning]
 **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`linux`)

```
$ file $(readlink -f $(type -p rename))
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

Comment: thanks, but the rename command given only seems to remove the quotes, looking at the man page now :)

Comment: If it removes only the quotes, then you have the wrong version like explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to do in python 2.x. You can use this logic in any language you want.

```
import string
a=raw_input('Enter the name of song')
a=a.replace('"', "")
a=a.replace('.mp', ' .mp3')
words = a.split()
print words[2]+'-'+words[0]+'_-_'+words[4]+words[5]
```

Logic:

I removed ", then make .mp to .mp3, then splitted the string, which created a list ( array ) and then printed the elements according to need.